# Is there a way to define the camera parameters myself?

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, rendering

I am working with Shapenet dataset which contains 3D information. I want to create images out of that dataset by defining the camera intrinsics and extrinsics on my own (so its like I will be defining where my camera is with respect to object and what will be the focal length and optical center of camera). Is there a concrete way by which I can pick some values for these ?

PS : I can load the shapenet models in some 3D viewing software and if I could extract the camera parameters might be using (since at any particular time, it is showing me an image)

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming-related

Comment: Are you searching for a way to extract the extrinsic and intrinsic camera parameters from the footage you got or do you already have the parameters and are looking for a way to apply the inverse projection to your images?

Comment: Look into OpenGL or any other rendering library, you can define a camera in that library, render your object and then save that render to an image. That said, this question is unclear and not related to programming but more of a badly worded open question

Comment: @eike Yes, I am trying to extract the intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters from the footage. 
I have .obj file from Shapenet dataset which I am loading in the viewer. In the viewer, I can rotate and translate the model as I like. So, what I am trying to do is to rotate/translate the model as I like to some suitable viewpoint and then extract the camera parameters of that snapshot

Comment: When your footage is from a 3D Model viewer, you can just look up the model-view and projection matrix that the viewer software uses. No need to extract it from the images.

Comment: For anyone else who might be trying to do the same thing. I was able to render the images from the 3d model of the objects in the shapenet dataset using the pyrender library.